# Is there any way to log all changes made to ColdFusion Administrator settings?

Tags: windows-server-2003, coldfusion

Is there any way to log all changes made to ColdFusion Administrator settings? Sometimes people make changes without documenting them, and then when something goes wrong, we have to search to find the cause of the problem. I'd like to have a log of all changes made, to make this search easier.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I sure could have used the answer a few months back when we couldn't get CF started and couldn't figure out why not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ColdFusion 7/8/9 don't have this capability.  However, ColdFusion 10, which is currently in beta has added audit logging in the ColdFusion Administrator as a new feature.